# Correct way to init firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, initialization

I am trying to initialize Firebase in flutter project. I use FutureBuilder to load this function:

```
static Future initializeFirebase({required BuildContext context}) async {
    try {
      FirebaseApp firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: FirebaseOptions(
              apiKey: "abc",
              authDomain: "def",
              projectId: "ghi",
              storageBucket: "jkl",
              messagingSenderId: "mno",
              appId: "pqr",
              measurementId: "stu"));
      return firebaseApp;
    } catch (err) {
      print("ERRRRR $err");
      throw err.toString();
    }
  }
```

when running in android and ios, it goes fine (nothing wrong), but whenever I run it in chrome it always throw `Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'` is there a way to solve this

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: when I define FirebaseApp firebaseApp =  await Firebase.initializeApp(....), from that line always throwing error (Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null')

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're missing the databaseUrl in your config.

```
FirebaseOptions(
              apiKey: "abc",
              authDomain: "def",
              projectId: "ghi",
              storageBucket: "jkl",
              messagingSenderId: "mno",
              appId: "pqr",
              measurementId: "stu",
              databaseURL: 'https://YOURDOMAIN.firebaseio.com',
));
```